# Blank Line File Reading

Tags: python, terminal-emulator

I am attempting to make an apple ][ (2) emulator for fun.

What I have tried is things like:

if line is '' then skip line

I am currently building the lines part. A file may read something like this:

```
1 [line of code 1]
2
3
4
5 [line of code 2]
6
7
8
9
10 [line of code 3]
```

(For those of you who don't know, with apple 2, you put ~10 lines of white space between lines, because there is no copy and paste)

If somebody used the 'list' command, it should print out:

```
1 [line of code 1]
5 [line of code 2]
10 [line of code 3]
```

Everything I try usually ends up doing one of the 2 following if I try to remove blank lines

```
2
4
6
8
10
```

OR

```
2 [
4 
6
8
10 [li
```

Comment: Its hard to say how code should be fixed without seeing some code. if this is a file being read into a list, you may want something like `[stripped for line in fileobj if (stripped:=line.strip())]`.

Comment: Can you give an runnable example of the code you have?

Answer (score 0):

You simply use:

```
for idx, ele in enumerate(lines):
    lines[idx] = ele.replace('\n', '')
```

This removes the '\n' from the file